# Is HTTP Server API in Windows OS Maintained

Tags: windows, httpserver, schannel

Is HTTP Server API in Windows OS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-api-start-page) still maintained. I see it supports only till SSLv3 as mentioned in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-server-api-features. Can it be made to work with TLS1.2. Thank You

Comment: Documentation might be outdated. Did you try it?

Comment: Thank You Anders. I tried the the sample code given at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-server-sample-application. Which this works for HTTP, it is not working for me for HTTPS. Could not find any other reference code. Also I am on Windows 11. Thank You.